# How do I get the Wordpress post to display the content instead of an image?

Tags: posts, themes, migration

I am working on migrating a Wordpress site to a test server. I imported all of the content & settings, and verified that every setting is the same as the old site. However, I'm having a problem that I can't find an answer to.

The theme the site is using is "Simplicity", which has a "mini-features" section. I have the section set up on the home page, and in the back end it tells the page to link the mini feature to the URL of a blog post. Unfortunately, instead of showing the content of the blog post, it's only showing an image assigned to the mini-feature.

I have checked Google, the Simplicity documentation, double checked every possible setting on the site, and I cannot find a solution. Can somebody PLEASE help me???

This is ONE page that the error is on...

OLD (working) site: http://www.archkit.com/key/the-basics/
NEW (not-working) site: http://scottera.com/key/the-basics/

Comment: How did you import the content?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that The Loop includes the_content();

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: if you provide a link to your site I can give you a more specific answer / code.

Comment: I just checked that, and it's not there but it's not there in the original file (on the old site) either. There is a bunch of "woo-options" that takes its place. If I can figure out which files the "woo" code is in, perhaps that's where something's missing...?

Comment: I think you're on the right track! Don't be afraid to experiment with inserting `the_content();` ...just make sure you've got server access and a working back up of whatever php files you're editing (just in case you break something).

Comment: How would it have gotten deleted in the transfer though? Could it be an entire file I'm missing (presumably in the theme folder)???

Oh, and I forgot to add...after I imported all of the content, the links worked UNTIL I changed the domain from archkit to scottera...does that help give anyone a clue?

Comment: Just add the_content(); where you want your content displayed ...and change any URLs that reference archkit to scottera.

Comment: Try to find the reference to the image you're seeing in the php code ...and replace it with a reference to the_content();

Comment: I wouldn't be able to see the image in the php code, since it comes from a custom post type...and all of the URLs have been changed to scottera. I just don't understand why it's working on the main site but not the new one...I'm ready to throw my laptop across the room I'm so frustrated!